# What is this hair loss at my cats ears and head?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, hairloss

[image]

As of now its limited to her head and ears, but I am afraid its spreading. She is loosing hair rapidly below her right eye. Can anyone tell me the actual name of the illness or any remedy? It will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to a veterinarian in your area? My first instict is that it looks like an infestation with a skin parasite, but you often need a vet to diagnose which parasite it actually is.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I am from a not so developed country. I found this abandoned litter of 4 kittens on my property. All the other once are completely fine and healthy.  only this one is having the said issue. Also other than this 'hair loss' problem this cat is also pretty healthy (as far as I can tell). 

Access to a vet is a really hard thing. Is their any general medication that you know of that I can administer my cat with???

Comment: @Elmy would it be useful to separate the ill kitten from the others?

Comment: you need a vet or a medical doctor to take a look at this to get it diagnosed and treated,you should in general not separate the kittens from their mother but this depends a lot on the age of the kittens and beside this if this is caused by parasites the kittens will most likely be infected too,depending on the type of parasites you too might get infected by this.

Comment: @trondhansen „abandoned litter“. I don’t think we need to worry about separating them from the mother? But I agree with you and Elmy: a local vet should look at the case and e.g. id a parasite.

Answer (score 1):

*Please keep in mind that I am not a vet.* I cannot diagnose your cat, but I suspect that she has skin mites.

There are many different types of mites and most of them are microscopic. They can live in skin pores or bite holes into the skin and they cause different skin conditions like mange or scabies. Many types of mites are highly infective and can even infect humans. If you notice tiny red dots on your skin or have itchy patches of skin, treat yourself against the mites as well.

The best treatment are special anti-parasitic shampoos and medications prescribed by a vet. If you don't have access to a vet, you can try home remedies, but they might not work as well.

**Acid**

Skin mites are vulnerable to acid, but the skin of your cat is vulnerable as well. The goal is to use a liquid that is too acidic for the mites but still tolerable for your cat. Usually people use a mix of 1 part apple cider vinegar and 1 part water. Rub this mixture into the cats fur and onto the hairless skin every 2 days.

Other types of vinegar work as well, but apple cider vinegar is mild to the skin and has a less pungent smell. If you only have lemons or limes available, **do not treat your cat with lemon juice, because all citrus fruits are toxic to cats**.

**Oil**

You can suffocate the mites by applying vegetable oil or fat to the skin. Typical oils that work well are olive oil, castor oil, coconut oil and neem oil. You can intensify the effect by crushing garlick into a very fine paste in a mortar and mixing it with the oil. Only use a little bit of garlic, because too much can be bad for your cat.

Rub some oil onto the bare patches of skin and also the surrounding skin that still has hair. You'll probably have to apply the oil twice a day because the cat will clean itself and lick it away.

**Risk of contagion**

All types of skin mites are highly contagious to other cats and many can also infect dogs and humans. You must assume that **all kittens are already infected**, you just don't see the signs yet. There's a chance that the other kittens have a stronger immune system and don't get infected, though.

If you have skin contact with the cat, you may also get infected. If you notice any kind of tiny red dots or itchyness on your skin, treat yourself with the same method you treat your cat. Since lemon juice is not toxic to humans, you can also rub lemon or lime juice on your itchy skin to treat yourself.

If the cat sits or lays on your bed, sofa or pillows, the mites can stay in that object and infect you or other cats. You should clean any pillows or blankets the cats sleep on.